# PIP install for scipy fails spectacularly on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to install the scipy package on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, only because gensim needs it, using pip (before anyone chimes in on switching to any of the twelve other python package managers: No). I have installed all the prereq packages:

- python 2.7
- libblas3
- liblapack3
- gcc
- gfortran
- python-dev
- libc6
- libatlas-base
- libatlas-dev
- python-build-essential

When I run pip install gensim, I get about ten full minutes of compiler warnings followed by several `virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory` errors. One of the compiler warnings that keeps coming up is:

```
/home/ubuntu/www/cool-project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
```

This is despite already having numpy installed:

```
(venv)ubuntu@box:~/www/cool-project$ pip install numpy --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Lastly, the final error message:

```
error: Command "c++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iscipy/sparse/sparsetools -I/home/ubuntu/www/cool-project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/bsr.o" failed with exit status 1
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: FWIW, I did `pip install gensim` in a virtualenv in Ubuntu 16.04 without problems.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-scipy` Default paths, compiler, compiler version, output style ?

Comment: Scipy is not just Python code. It has too much Fortran and C code in it to be built. Hence special care is needed. Did you try https://scipy.org/install.html#ubuntu-debian ? While you are at it switch to Python 3 maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that what was needed was for pip itself to be upgraded to the latest version: `pip install --upgrade pip`. After that was done, scipy installed without a problem.